# Javascript: How to parse a json array without knowing the key name?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to parse the following json:

```
{"key_410441":{"hashId":"hash123","tube_id":"4accdefk31"}}
```

Where `key_410441` is the entry's name representing the object's value, and the following array is the object's data.

How can I retrieve it's value?

```
function defined(json) {
   for (var i in json) {
      var objId = json[i]. ????
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just loop over `json[i]` the same way?

Comment: `for (var i in json) {
      alert(json[i].hashId)
   }`

Comment: which value? If you mean the `{"hashId","tube_id"}` object, just `var objId = json[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Robo Robok said, use    `Object.keys(object`)

if your json look like `{"key_410441":{"hashId":"hash123","tube_id":"4accdefk31"}}`

```
   function defined(json) {
        var hashId = json[Object.keys(json)[0]].hashId
        var tube_id = json[Object.keys(json)[0]].tube_id
      }
   }
```

you can use shortcut `json[Object.keys(json)]` because you have olny one object

> key_410441

Answer (score 0):

Object keys are returned in form of an array by `Object.keys(object)`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using jquery and ajax to get a json from an external file. Then the piece of code would be:-

```
$.getJSON("aa.json", function(data) {
                    var obj = Object.keys(data),
                        json = data[obj];

                    for(var s in json) {
                        console.log(json[s]);
                    }
                });
```